# How to get rows in a table that start from a specific date and time in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sqldatetime

In one of my SQL Server tables, I have te following rows:

| Date | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 10:00:00.0000000 |
| 2021-10-01 | 11:00:00.0000000 |
| 2021-10-01 | 12:00:00.0000000 |
| 2021-10-02 | 10:00:00.0000000 |
| 2021-10-02 | 11:00:00.0000000 |
| 2021-10-02 | 12:00:00.0000000 |
| 2021-10-03 | 10:00:00.0000000 |
| 2021-10-03 | 11:00:00.0000000 |
| 2021-10-03 | 12:00:00.0000000 |

I'd like to get rows that start from a specific `Date`, and then from a specific `Time`. For instance, passing `2021-10-02` and `12:00:00.0000000`, I'd like to get the last four rows because `2021-10-02` is considered the "starting date", and then `12:00:00.0000000` is considered the "starting time". Unfortunately, I'm not so good at SQL. I guess nested queries should be the way to go.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your query that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself, and then explain how that query isn't giving you the results you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be a little "2 pronged" about this. You'll need to check the date is on `2021-10-02` and on or after `12:00:00.0000000`, or on or after `2021-10-03`:

```sql
SELECT {YourColumns}
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE (YourDate = '20210102' AND YourTime >= '12:00:00')
   OR YourDate >= '20210103';
```

Comment: Just use greater than so you're comparing the same argument twice.